# XOR enryption error char to int loses precision

Tags: c++, xor

I'm having trouble getting this program to work on a UNIX server. It seems to work just fine on Codeblocks but then using Putty it gives the error "cas from 'char*' to 'int' loses precision.

I'm trying to have the user input a sentence and a word as the key. then output the sentence only with spaces in between each letter.

Help with this error would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(){

string sentence;
string encrypted;
string unencrypt;
char key[] = "x";

cout << "Enter sentence: ";
getline(cin, sentence);

cout << "Enter key: ";
cin >> key;

for (int temp = 0; temp < sentence.size(); temp++){
encrypted += sentence[temp] ^ (int(key) + temp) % 2;
}
cout << "Encrypted = " << encrypted;

for (int temp = 0; temp < sentence.size(); temp++){
unencrypt += sentence[temp] ^ (int(key) + temp) % 2;
}
cout << endl;
cout << "Unencrypted = " << unencrypt;


return 0;

}
```

Comment: Is using XOR encryption ever a good idea?

Comment: `int(key)` is dodgy - what is that supposed to do exactly?

Comment: I'll give it the benefit of the doubt and assume this is just for fun/homework.

Comment: This is for homework so obviously the encryption isn't secure but I'm required to have an output like h e l l o w o r l d for an input of hello world and key hello. int key should use the inputted key in the encryption process but let me know if there is a better for loop or type to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's giving an error because "key" is an array with 2 elements.
You'll want to dereference `key`.
`int(*key)`

And you should avoid C-style casts: `static_cast<int>(*key)`

And your encryption/decryption routines are the same.

Comment: "And your encryption/decryption routines are the same." - of course, it's XOR.

Comment: He's not XORing the encrypted text; he's XORing the same thing twice.

Comment: Yeah, thanks I just realized they are the same, do you know how I would reverse the encryption with basically the same for loop? Also your method worked on the server it just says core dumped after it runs, but at least the encryption part worked.

Comment: sry haven't noticed it. @androidguy: you have to decrpyt the encrpyted value. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29

Comment: What're you feeding it as key? You can't give it more than one character (you only reserved space for one). You can make encryption/decryption the same function if you pass it a string argument to iterate over.

Comment: I'm using the user input of something like hello as the key? Can I do more than one letter using a char? Because I wasn't able to get it to work doing something like string key = "";

Comment: You could make `key` a `std::string` instead of a `char[]`, but then you'll have to do more than just casting `key` to `int` (eg. something like turning sentence and key into hex, XORing them, and making them strings again. They might not fall in the range of printable characters, though).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. Yeah that's why it's tough for me to figure out how to encrypt using normal characters and output the encryption as simply the input but with spaces. Most tutorials just show encrypting for security purpose which makes sense.